# ¿Alguien me puede asesorar con este error?

Tags: mongodb

Cannot connect to the MongoDB at localhost:27017.

Error:
Network is unreachable. Reason: couldn't connect to server localhost:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to localhost:27017 (127.0.0.1:27017) :: caused by :: No se puede establecer una conexi�n ya que el equipo de destino deneg� expresamente dicha conexi�n.

Comment: Hombre, no he usado MongoDB pero parece que el servidor de base de datos no está escuchando en esa ip y/o puerto, o bien las credenciales no son válidas.

Comment: Tal como te comentan, no existe una instancia de MongoDB en dicho puerto. Sin embargo, falta contexto para poder ayudarte. ¿Qué sistema operativo usas? ¿Qué versión de MongoDB? ¿Sabes si el servicio de MongoDB inicia automáticamente al iniciar el equipo? Veo tu cadena de conexión que apunta a `localhost`, por lo cual MongoDB debe estar instalado en el mismo equipo desde el que intentas la conexión. ¿Te has asegurado que el antivirus o el firewall no bloquean el puerto? Saludos